# Find specific data in MongoDB via NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I need to find specific data in my MongoDB for the rest API but it's returning null.

```
app.get('/api/v1/champions/:name', (req, res) => {
    db.find({"champions": req.params.name}, (err, champion) => {
        res.json(err)
    })
    })
```

Here is my MongoDB Schema:

```
champions: {
    champ_name_1: {
        dmg: Number,
        cost: Number
    },
    champ_name_2: {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are checking to see if a key exists in the champions object you'll need to write the query differently.

If your data was formatted like this then your query would work. (champions is a String)

```
{
    "champions": "champ_name_1",
    "dmg": 123,
    "cost": 123
}
```

To check if a key exists in an object in mongo, use a query like this.

```
const champKey = 'champions.' + req.params.name;
db.find({ [champKey]: { $exists: true } });
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Comment: Edit:
I created a object to pass variable into db.find().

`code`
let params = {}:
params[champKey} = {$exists: true};
`code`
db.find(params)...

Answer (score 0):

you can use mongoose package 
[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)

and simply use the mongoose's  `find()` methond to find particular data as providing to it.

For Example: find({_id: MY_ID_HERE});